# How do you change the color of your text when typing in clan chat?

Tags: clash-royale

I've noticed that some people have colored text in the clan chat. How do you change the color of the text?

Comment: Try <c(colorcode)> text </c> bit like html if you know what I mean

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature has been discontinued.

Comment: I was too late to try this in game, doesn't work anymore sadly.. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the color of the text, you have to use the following template.

```
<c[hexcode]>"message"</c>
```

An example of this would be

```
<cff0000>This will make the text red</c>
```

*Note, this no longer works as it has been patched out of the game a few patches ago.

Answer (score 2):

`<ccc0033>message</c>` Use this format except change the word message to the sentence you want and it will be red. You can make it other colors by looking up color-hex.com. You have to replace the (cc0033) at the beginning but keep the first c.

Answer (score 1):

The codes are:

```
Light Pink   - <cffcce7>
Red          - <cff0000>
Teal         - <c008080>
Bright Blue  - <c0000ff>
Turquoise    - <c00ffff>
Coral        - <cff7373>
Bright green - <c00ff00>
Purple       - <c800080>
Yellow       - <cffff00>
Light Blue   - <cc6e2ff>
Brown        - <ca52a2a>
```

Then you type your message no space in between the tags and the message.  After your you type  right next to the text no space and send the text color will change.

Answer (score -2):

You can change the color of your clan in the following way:

```
  <c (color name in hex)>(text)</c>
```

An example:

```
  <c336699>Good game</c>
```

This will result in a blue-coloured text "Good game".

**Important notice: The commands above are *case sensitive*, so write "c" instead of "C".**

Comment: i just tried this, and it doesnt work.

Comment: You can just use angle brackets as long as it's in code markup. I'd make that edit myself but I'm not entirely sure what exactly the format needs to be

Comment: Is it fine now? @Dragonrage