# How to change the color of my name?

Tags: clash-royale

Recently I encountered someone with a green colored name. I saw that it is possible to change your name (in the settings, but just ONCE), and I maybe want a colored nickname too. How do I accomplish that? In the same way as in normal chat (explained [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259936/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-your-text-when-typing-in-clan-chat))?

I do not want to test it myself before I know for sure, due to the change-it-once policy.

Screenshot (removed clans):

[image: Screenshot of colored nickname]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you suspected, you accomplish this the same way as changing text in the chat box.

For completeness, the code to do that is:

`<c######>name</c>`

Replace the `######` with the hex code color you wish to use.

---

Unfortunately, unlike the chatbox, you are very limited on the length of characters you can use.

There are a few basic colors that only require a single digit:

```
2 Red
3 Green
4 Blue
5 Turquoise
6 Pink
7 Yellow
9 Dark Red
```

If you want to use one of these colors, it will save you quite a bit of space to spend those characters on your actual name.

In case you have doubts, you can see that the name change is going to go through correctly before you confirm the change. Here is a screenshot of my game which shows the change to blue:
[image: Text Box displaying colors]

And again on the confirmation screen:
[image: Confirmation screen confirming colors]

Comment: May be worth mentioning that Supercell will likely patch in some sanitization of their inputs and your name could end up looking pretty stupid after-the-fact

Comment: It's possible, but I'd rather not speculate. It's just as likely that if they do that they will do pattern matching (regex) to remove all of the markup. Especially since there are players in the top rankings that have done this.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that there is a 15 character limit and <c#></c> takes up 8 so your name has to be 7 or fewer characters. My name was 9 characters and it ended up butchered.

Comment: @am17torres How could it have ended up butchered if you're able to see the preview before you change your name?

Comment: @Insane, the preview is weird because the first two characters I definitely typed weren't there. The <c disappears immediately, I just assumed the UI was buggy and decided to risk it. That being said, if your name is short enough the UI does display the color  in the preview and you'll know ahead of time if it's going to work.

Comment: @am17torres I know it is too late but the confirm screen will show it correctly.

Answer (score -2):

It is accomplished exactly how you change chat text colour:

```
   <c(hexcode)>(name)</c>
```

However, be extremely careful that **a future game update may *remove this feature*, and your name may get permanently corrupted**, because you can't change your name again! (Except if you contact Supercell, perhaps.)

Comment: you do realize that you posted the same answer as Michael, 4 hours after he posted his?