# Clash Royale - Maximum coloured name length

Tags: clash-royale

To write coloured text in Clash Royale you have to use this template, as seen [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259936/how-do-you-change-the-color-of-your-text-when-typing-in-clan-chat):

```
<cff0000>Red text</c>
```

But your name can be 15 characters long, at max. That means that I have just two characters left, after the template. Yet I see some people with four letter coloured names. How can I achieve longer names and What is the maximum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a bit wrong. This template is for text in the chat only. As there is character length limit you use c1-9 instead of crrggbb. Refer to [this](http://clashroyalearena.com/tips/use-colored-name-clash-royale) for color to cX correlation.

I have no idea how long your name can be after applying color to it. I have someone in my clan with 7 colored characters.

Comment: Thanks! Being `<c#></c>` 8 characters long, that fixed maximum length for a coloured name to 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the limit is 17 characters leaving 9 characters for a name after the ">c#>123456789>/c>".

Had to post the first and 3rd as greater than because it thought I was writing code with the less than key. the first and 3rd greater than should be less than sign for those that do not know how to write in code.

Comment: It's better to write them as code, that gives you `<c#>123456789</c>`. However, limit is 15 characters for me, so that fixes maximum length for a coloured name to 7.

Answer (score 0):

You have a (very) limited number of characters, indeed. However, **you can introduce colours defined by less than 6 characters in the hexcode.** It's appropiate to insert a 1 or 2 characters long hexcode, in order to save space.

For example:

```
  <c4>Jeffrey</c>
```

This will result in a blue "Jeffrey" name, however the short hexcode might save a lot of room for the nickname, with a **nickname of maximum of 7 characters.** So, use this method if you want to save space for your name, *instead of spending them on a long hexcode.*